# Reading specific characters from a file in Python

Tags: python-2.7, file-io

Suppose I want to read file in this format:

```
2

300   234 2 3

23444
```

If I use `readline()` it iterates over the entire line. What I want is for it to read only the numbers nothing else. How should I do this??

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You'll have to use regex.

Comment: Read them how? Should each line be a single integer? Multiple integers? Always integers? Always a single space? Is `readline` the only thing you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module.

```
import re

numbers = re.findall('[0-9]+', readline())
```

It will return all numbers as a list.

Answer (score -1):

Use readline() to get the entire line as a string, then split the string using split(), which will return a list of strings (in your case, numbers) in the line.

Example:

```
line = yourFile.readline()
numList = line.split()
```

Now numList contains the numbers that were on that line.

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split